# Android Google Maps: how to remove an overlay from the map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have overlays on my map which are roughly created like this:

```
for(String date : dates)
{
MapCustomTileProvider tileProvider = getMapCustomTileProviderForDate(date); // MapCustomeTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider
mMap.addTileOverlay(tileProvider.overlayOptions);
tileProviders.add(tileProvider);
}
```

Later in my code, I want to make some of these overlays transparent/invisible:

```
   for (MapTileProvider tileProvider : tileProviders) {

            tileProvider.overlayOptions.visible(false);
}
```

But the map does not redraw.

How to force the refresh of the map ?

By the way, is it possible to adjust the transparency (alpha) of an overlay ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: For refresh check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10109796/4247543

Comment: Thanks but this code (map.getOverlays().clear();
  map.invalidate();) is deprecated :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addTileOverlay` method returns a [`TileOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay) object that you can work with:

```
TileOverlay overlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(tileProvider.overlayOptions);
overlay.setVisible(false); // Make the overlay invisible
overlay.remove(); // Remove the tile overlay from the map.
```

You may want to change your `tileProviders` to be `List<TileOverlay>` to work with your overlays:

```
List<TileOverlay> tileOverlays = new ArrayList<TileOverlay>
tileOverlays.add(mMap.addTileOverlay(tileProvider.overlayOptions));

// ...

for (TileOverlay tileOverlay : tileOverlays) {
    tileOverlay.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Brillant ! :) Thanks. Now, do you know how to adjust the transparency (alpha) of an overlay ? Or a workaround... Thanks !!!

Comment: It depends on your `MapCustomTileProvider` implementation but you will return a byte array and you can work with the output as a `Bitmap`

Comment: Thanks. I think it will be a mess because sometimes I need the same overlay with transparency, and some other times the overlay without transparency. I will see... Thanks for your great help anyway.